# How do you describe a person who delights in prodding your weaknesses.

Tags: expressions

How do you describe a person who delights in prodding your weaknesses. Example: a loan officer of a bank who picks at your plan in a way that is embarrassing and he keeps it up for half an hour.

Comment: _Antagonist_ might work.

Comment: From the Star Trek episode The Trouble with Tribbles: "Kirk may be a swaggering, overbearing, tin-plated dictator with delusions of godhood. But he's not soft"

Answer (score 4):

In terms of 'prodding', ***[pernicious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pernicious)***:

> having a harmful effect, especially in a *gradual* or subtle way

In terms of taking delight, ***[sadistic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sadistic)***:

> *Deriving pleasure* from inflicting pain, suffering, or humiliation on others

(and the ol' [schadenfreude](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/schadenfreude) which seems to turn up here often..)

Answer (score 3):

It can be said that they '***enjoy*** [**pushing your buttons**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Push%20buttons)'

> v. - to push buttons
>
> 1. To deliberately irritate
> 2. To intentionally provoke another without reason
> 3. To wear away at the patience of someone until that person wants to 
>      slap you
> 4. To capitalize on the emotional vulnerabilities of another
>
> *www.urbandictionary.com*

Comment: This describes the action, not the person

Comment: @Lamar Saying that someone 'enjoys [doing something]' is a description of a facet of the person, not the action they enjoy doing.

Comment: true... I just read the highlighted and quoted text ... my oversight

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for...

> [<sub>(thefreedictionary)</sub>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vindictive)
>   **vindictive**
>   1. *Disposed to seek revenge; revengeful.*
>   2. *Marked by or resulting from a desire to hurt; spiteful.*

Note that etymologically speaking, the first definition above is the "original, true" meaning (from Latin *vindicta = vengeance, revenge*), but I never hear it used with positive associations (i.e. - exacting *justifiable* vengeance in response to unjustified bad treatment). And the word is commonly used in the second sense,  in contexts where there it simply identifies a person who enjoys causing distress to others, with no implication of "retaliation" (justified or not).

Comment: When a court awards a *vindictive* damages to plaintiffs, they will be positively happy with the ruling. It is one of very rare positive associations.

Comment: @Rathony: I've never heard that usage - maybe it's a US thing. In the UK those are called ***punitive*** (occasionally ***exemplary***) damages. Legal "vindictiveness" sounds to me like the start of a slippery slope.

Answer (score 0):

*Passive-aggressive* comes to mind, although it seems to be way broader.

What you describe sounds like a *cruel faultfinder* who enjoys criticism at the expense of others.

Answer (score 0):

Schadenfreudenista if you play it fast and loose.

Comment: `<unsolicited side note>`As someone who works with Loan Officers, they don't get paid unless your Loan closes, so even if it seems like they're delighting in your discomfort, it _probably_ comes from a genuine desire to help ( although the person themself may still be a jerk )`</unsolicited side note>`

Answer (score -2):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callous 
I would say callous and indifferent because such people don't have compassion and care for others feelings and are somehow indifferent too.

Comment: Someone who lacks compassion does not necessarily seek to bully; they are simply unsympathetic to people who are bullied. They don't try to provoke feelings of embarassment or insecurity in others; they simply don't care *what* feelings they provoke by their words or actions.

Comment: @choster that's true . I wanted to emphasize 'callous' and somehow explain it in my own words